# how to send hexadecimal values using gcdasyncsocket?

Tags: ios, arrays, sockets, hex

I have an array with nsstring like:

<__NSArrayM 0x20860370>(
3a,
4d,
00,
03,
04,
00,
07,
00,
0d,
0a
)

how can i send this data as real hexadecimal values using GCDAsyncsocket? I need to send all this values for every time i call the function for write to socket (es: 3a,
4d,
00,
03,
04,
00,
07,
00,
0d,
0a
)

I try using a function like:

```
[socket writeData:[array dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withTimeout:1 tag:0];
```

But in this way i send character, not hex values...

thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, you go through the array, convert each string to an `uint8_t`, then append it to an `NSMutableData` or so...

Comment: i can't send in uint8_t i must send in ASCII hex

Comment: What? What you wrote doesn't make sense...